# QNetworkAccessManager. HTTPS. "Error downloading ... - server replied: Forbidden"

Tags: c++, qt, http, https

Мне необходимо выполнить вход на сайте headhunter через приложение. Для этого использую http. На главной странице сайта отправляю POST запрос, в результате чего мне возвращается ошибка:

"Error downloading https://novosibirsk.hh.ru/ - server replied: Forbidden"

С чем это связано не понятно, тут проблема, что я не правильно что-то пишу, или это сайт блокирует такую деятельность? В теме я новичок, собственно изучением проблематике сейчас и занимаюсь на практике. В общем помогите решить проблему, код прилагается:

Подключено следующее:
"QSslSocket"
"QtNetwork/QtNetwork"

Сам код запроса:

```
void MainWindow::login()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QUrl urlDoLogin("https://novosibirsk.hh.ru/");

    QString userName=  "";    //  e-mail
    QString password=  "";  //  пароль

    /* Формирование  запроса на основе пользовательских данных */
    QByteArray postData;
// сформирован пакет при просмотре что отправляет браузер при заполнении логина 
// и пароля после нажатия кнопки входа. Смотрел в браузере гугл при помощи кнопки F12 и 
// вкладки Network и поля FormData
    postData+= "username=" +  QUrl::toPercentEncoding( userName.toUtf8() );
    postData+= "&password="+  QUrl::toPercentEncoding( password.toUtf8() );
    postData+= "&backUrl=https://novosibirsk.hh.ru/";
    postData+= "&action=Войти";
    postData+= "&_xsrf=762958505760cc6f18d17880ad062157";


    QNetworkRequest request(urlDoLogin);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding","identity"); // Отменяю сжатие что бы, можно было нормально просматривать контент снифером

    QNetworkReply* reply= manager->post(request,postData);
        connect( reply, SIGNAL(finished()),
                 this, SLOT(replyFinished())
               );
}

void MainWindow::replyFinished()
{
  QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender());
  if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
      QByteArray content= reply->readAll();
      QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("cp1251");
      ui->textEdit->setPlainText(codec->toUnicode(content.data()) );
    }
  else qDebug()<<reply->errorString();

  reply->deleteLater();
}
```

Comment: Залогинился через программу здесь на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fru.stackoverflow.com%2f
и всё получилось как надо. В чём может быть дело?
Использую OpenSSL 1.0.2о

Comment: https://nsk.zarplata.ru/ 
на этом сайте происходит то же самое, только ошибка :
"Error downloading https://nsk.zarplata.ru/login - server replied: Not Allowed"

Comment: Смотрели через инструмент разработчика в браузере какие запросы посылаются при авторизации?

Comment: Вот всё, что отправляется в поле для headhunter FormData:


username:mail@gmail.com
password:asdas2
backUrl:https://novosibirsk.hh.ru/
action:Войти
_xsrf:762958505760cc6f18d17880ad062157

и вот такой link adress:https://novosibirsk.hh.ru/account/login?backurl=%2F

Однако ещё там есть другой какой-то логин с  link adress: https://novosibirsk.hh.ru/account/login?state=mismatch&backurl=%2F
В нём вместо FormData - Query String Parameters:
state:mismatch
backurl:/

Comment: Возможно, дело в _xsrf. Оно по идее будет каждый раз генерироваться. Т.е. сначала нужно загрузить страницу, после отправить запрос. Если сразу отправлять запрос  без _xsrf или с невалидным (например, старым) сервер должен отказать запросу

Comment: Проверил два раза, он одно и тоже генерирует в этом поле
762958505760cc6f18d17880ad062157
762958505760cc6f18d17880ad062157

Comment: А вы попробуйте через другой ip зайти или через некоторое, думаю будет другое значение.

Comment: А как тогда можно прогрузить страницу и узнать корректный на данный момент xsrf?? Обычным GET запросом? Но как я там увижу xsrf? И кстати на втором сайте, на котором почти такая же проблема получилась, xsrf не было вовсе.

Comment: Обычным GET-запросом. Ищите теги input, в одном из них будет _xsrf (либо запрос делается через ajax, тогда нужно будет найти откуда посылается, но это вряд ли). Значит на втором сайте для того запроса не было такой защиты и можно сделать подделку межсайтового запроса

Comment: Не помогло, ошибка та же.  нашёл значение. скопировал в глобальную переменную и передал во вторую функцию и передал на сайт. Причём сделал на всю программу один QNetworkAccessManager, а то по логике подключение должно быть одно.

Comment: Хотя значение и отличается от того, которое давал браузеру, но каждый новый заход не меняет этого числа

Answer (score 1):

Проблему обнаружил. Была в том, что я заголовки не все прописал, а

```
request.setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding","identity");
```

вообще оказался не правильным, т.к. там были совсем другие форматы. Изменил так и все заработало

```
 request.setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br");
```

которые указаны были при просмотре через F12. Сейчас ошибка 302, с ней разбираюсь, но пока вроде понятно, что это переадресация и нужно просто реализовать её как надо. Хотя и приходящий URL переадрресации какой-то косячный, как-будто там 5 URL и с этим URL открытие страницу через запрос GET не проходит:
https://novosibirsk.hh.ru/hhid/authBegin/;https;novosibirsk.hh.ru;443;/account/login

Comment: Хорошо, что вы смогли разобраться